# Recursion in python, e.g insertionsort

Tags: python, memory, recursion

I tried to create a insertionsort function in python, and I can't really understand what's wrong..

I know that when I call the function again, Python doesn't delete the last time the function ran, how can I just dump the current function when I call the next? (when I call the function on 'return')

I did noticed that for small lists (60+-) it runs good, but for bigger lists it doesn't..

Thank you!

```
def insertsort(lst,k=1):
    for i in range(len(lst)-k):
        if lst[i] > lst[i+k]:
            lst[i],lst[i+k]=lst[i+k],lst[i]
            return insertsort(lst)
    return None
```

Comment: Did you mean `return lst` in the last line?

Comment: no, its in-place..

Comment: Why would you want to implement insertion sort recursively?  Its primary use is as a _simple_, _light-weight_ stable sort for small amounts of data.  Is this a homework question?  Just practicing recursion for its own sake?

Comment: didn't know that was the use of insertsort, but I did it because it's seems to be more efficient, and I call this function when I shellsort..
that's why I implemented insertion sort recursively..

it's for me, I want to make all kind of sorts, and practice recursion..
thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use recursion to implement this algorithm.

```
def insertsort(lst):
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        for j in range(i):
            if lst[i] < lst[j]:
                lst.insert(j, lst.pop(i))
                break
    return lst
```

Test:

```
>>> insertsort([6, 5, 3, 1, 8, 7, 2, 4])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah I made one with while(inside the first for loop, same efficiency in worst case), but if I take for example a 40-length list, the recursion one is significantly faster..
I appreciate the answer, but I want to know if the recursion one is possible
thanks!